# Laravel queue job failing for using mailable

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs

This is my job file
public $email;

```
public function __construct($email)
{
    $this -> email = $email;
}
public function handle(): void
{
    Mail::to($this -> email)->send(new Sample_Mail());
    // echo $this -> email;
}
```

It's getting accessed from the listener.
This is the listener file's method

```
public function handle(MailEvent $event): void
    {
        dispatch(new MailJob($event -> email));
    }
```

When I give php artisan queue:work, it's running but the job is getting failed. And I checked the database and rows are getting added when I execute it. As you can see in the job file I tried echoing the email thinking that could be the problem but actually that works but when I tried to use mailable it's not working. I imported everything properly and if I try to execute that mailable in my controller it works fine as well.
Thank you zlatan for telling me about the exception column
This is the exception

```
Symfony\Component\Mime\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Unable to open path "image.jpg". in C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\symfony\mime\Part\TextPart.php:154
Stack trace:
#0 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\symfony\mime\Part\AbstractPart.php(50): Symfony\Component\Mime\Part\TextPart->bodyToIterable()
#1 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\symfony\mime\Part\AbstractMultipartPart.php(71): Symfony\Component\Mime\Part\AbstractPart->toIterable()
#2 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\symfony\mime\Part\AbstractPart.php(50): Symfony\Component\Mime\Part\AbstractMultipartPart->bodyToIterable()
#3 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\symfony\mime\Message.php(125): Symfony\Component\Mime\Part\AbstractPart->toIterable()
#4 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\symfony\mime\RawMessage.php(49): Symfony\Component\Mime\Message->toIterable()
#5 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\symfony\mailer\Transport\Smtp\Stream\AbstractStream.php(112): Symfony\Component\Mime\RawMessage->toIterable()
#6 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\symfony\mailer\Transport\Smtp\SmtpTransport.php(225): Symfony\Component\Mailer\Transport\Smtp\Stream\AbstractStream::replace('\r\n.', '\r\n..', Object(Generator))
#7 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\symfony\mailer\Transport\AbstractTransport.php(69): Symfony\Component\Mailer\Transport\Smtp\SmtpTransport->doSend(Object(Symfony\Component\Mailer\SentMessage))
#8 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\symfony\mailer\Transport\Smtp\SmtpTransport.php(137): Symfony\Component\Mailer\Transport\AbstractTransport->send(Object(Symfony\Component\Mime\Email), Object(Symfony\Component\Mailer\DelayedEnvelope))
#9 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Mail\Mailer.php(573): Symfony\Component\Mailer\Transport\Smtp\SmtpTransport->send(Object(Symfony\Component\Mime\Email), Object(Symfony\Component\Mailer\DelayedEnvelope))
#10 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Mail\Mailer.php(335): Illuminate\Mail\Mailer->sendSymfonyMessage(Object(Symfony\Component\Mime\Email))
#11 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Mail\Mailable.php(205): Illuminate\Mail\Mailer->send('sample', Array, Object(Closure))
#12 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\Localizable.php(19): Illuminate\Mail\Mailable->Illuminate\Mail\{closure}()
#13 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Mail\Mailable.php(198): Illuminate\Mail\Mailable->withLocale(NULL, Object(Closure))
#14 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Mail\Mailer.php(357): Illuminate\Mail\Mailable->send(Object(Illuminate\Mail\Mailer))
#15 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Mail\Mailer.php(301): Illuminate\Mail\Mailer->sendMailable(Object(App\Mail\Sample_Mail))
#16 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Mail\PendingMail.php(124): Illuminate\Mail\Mailer->send(Object(App\Mail\Sample_Mail))
#17 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\app\Jobs\MailJob.php(37): Illuminate\Mail\PendingMail->send(Object(App\Mail\Sample_Mail))
#18 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(36): App\Jobs\MailJob->handle()
#19 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Util.php(41): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#20 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\Container\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
#21 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(35): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#22 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(662): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#23 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher.php(128): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#24 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(141): Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher->Illuminate\Bus\{closure}(Object(App\Jobs\MailJob))
#25 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(App\Jobs\MailJob))
#26 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher.php(132): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#27 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler.php(123): Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher->dispatchNow(Object(App\Jobs\MailJob), false)
#28 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(141): Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler->Illuminate\Queue\{closure}(Object(App\Jobs\MailJob))
#29 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(App\Jobs\MailJob))
#30 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler.php(122): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#31 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler.php(70): Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler->dispatchThroughMiddleware(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), Object(App\Jobs\MailJob))
#32 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job.php(98): Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler->call(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), Array)
#33 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Worker.php(439): Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job->fire()
#34 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Worker.php(389): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->process('database', Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#35 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Worker.php(176): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->runJob(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), 'database', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#36 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand.php(137): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->daemon('database', 'default', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#37 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand.php(120): Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->runWorker('database', 'default')
#38 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(36): Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->handle()
#39 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Util.php(41): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#40 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\Container\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
#41 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(35): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#42 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(662): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#43 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php(211): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#44 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\symfony\console\Command\Command.php(326): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#45 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php(180): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#46 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(1081): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#47 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(320): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#48 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(174): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#49 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(201): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#50 C:\VSC\LARAVEL PHP\Week-8-Task\artisan(35): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#51 {main}
```

Actually it's the image in public folder.

```
public function attachments(): array
    {
        return [
            Attachment::fromPath('image.jpg'),
        ];
    }
```

I am trying to access that in the attachments can I get a solution on how to access that here?

Comment: What is the error? If your queue driver is database, all of the failed jobs will be stored in ```failed_jobs``` table. Please paste the exception, we can't help you without knowing that.

Comment: Based on the exception above, ```image.jpg``` file can't be found in the path you provided. Where is this image located in your project? Is it a public path, or storage, or somewhere else? You need to specify that in the ```fromPath()``` method